# Can someone work on remote online internship, while on Schengen visa in Europe?

Tags: visa, schengen, working

I will be in Europe this summer on a Schengen visa. I have got offer for an internship where I'll be contributing code online and chat with mentor. It is paid. Am I allowed to work on it while I am in Schengen area?

Organization paying is not based out of Europe.

EDIT: I have a Guest Scientist visa for Germany sponsored by a research lab.

Comment: Is your visa a tourist visa ?

Comment: I have a Guest Scientist visa for Germany sponsored by a research lab.

Comment: So you already have a contract with the sponsoring research lab that entitles you to do research and lecture at this research lab. You are asking if you can work for another institution ?

Comment: Yes, in parallel. That would increase my total working hours but won't comprise on my contract with the lab. Also work will be online and in no way related to any German organization.

Comment: Even if it is online, you are working in Germany. I'm not putting this as an answer because I can't find definitive german references, but the Guest scientist visa explicitly allow you to work (and get paid) by the sponsoring institution, other work is not mentioned. My feeling is that you are not allowed to do that. If you were, it would at least imply declaring that income to germany and pay taxes on it. Maybe a reader from germany might offer a more precise information.

Answer (score 1):

*De jure* there are dozens of complex laws and regulations regarding remote employment, under which you may or may not need a special visa in order to work in a given country. Tax laws are an additional complication, where countries such as the UK can deem you as a tax resident for [spending as little as 16 days](https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/residence) on British soil.

*De facto*, as long as you don't mention your remote job to immigration personnel at the airport, there's a 99.99% chance no one will ever find out. There are millions of people breaking the law by being employed at *on-site* jobs in any given country, so digital nomads are a pretty low priority for law enforcement. This especially valid in a country like Mexico where law enforcement isn't particularly worried about foreign tourists working during their travels.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?